# Google+ Button: Login for .clearScopes() is working and setScope() is not

Tags: android, google-plus

I am running into a problem understanding how **PlusClient.Builder.clearScope().build()** differs from **PlusClient.Builder.setScope().build()**.  In the first case my plus one button is working properly, but in the latter case the button is grayed out without any G+ counts appearing.

Why would calling **setScope()** cause this issue?

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton;

public class SignInActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
  implements View.OnClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener
{
 private final String TAG = SignInActivity.class.getSimpleName();
 private final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;
 private final int PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
 private PlusOneButton mPlusOneBtn;
 private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
 private PlusClient mPlusClient;
 private Resources mRes; private String mURL;
 private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_in_activity);
    mRes = getResources();
    mURL = mRes.getString(R.string.share_url);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_dude).setOnClickListener(this);
    mPlusOneBtn = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_standard_button);
    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).clearScopes().build();
    mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     mPlusClient.connect();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     mPlusClient.disconnect();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mPlusOneBtn.initialize(mPlusClient, mURL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
 }
}
```

[image: Working plus one button]

But now when I use .setScopes(), the standard plus one button is grayed out.

```
    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).
            .setScopes(Scopes.APP_STATE).setScopes(Scopes.GAMES)
            .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN).setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();
```

[image: Grayed out plus one button]

res/layout/sign_in_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sign_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button_dude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sign_in_button_dude"
            android:text="@string/sign_out_button_name"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/revoke_access_button"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sign_out_button"
            android:text="@string/revoke_access_button_name"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sign_row"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >

        <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
            xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
            android:id="@+id/plus_one_standard_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            plus:size="standard" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_status"
            android:layout_below="@+id/plus_one_standard_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Default status" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Note that setScopes replaces all existing scopes - you should use `setScopes(Scopes.APP_STATE, Scopes.GAMES, Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE)` instead.

Comment: I tried your code.    *mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setScopes(Scopes.APP_STATE, Scopes.GAMES, Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE).build();*    but unfortunately I still end up with the +1 grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

try initializing the mPlusOneBtn in the onConnected callback:

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mPlusOneBtn.initialize(mPlusClient, mURL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

from the docs at http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html:

"Use the PlusClient after the asynchronous connect() method has been called and your listener's onConnected(android.os.Bundle) method is called."

If that doesn't work, make sure the PlusClient is initialized properly, check what onConnectionFailed returns

```
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    //check what result says
}
```